# How do I get content (JSON object) of an html file from my iPhone app?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, json

I have an iPhone app which gets a response from a php file. This response generates an html file where the body contains a json object. How do I retrieve this JSON object ?

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM userData WHERE username = '$username'";  
    $result = mysql_query($query);  
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        sendResponse(200, json_encode('SUCCESS Notification'));
    } else { 
    $query = "INSERT INTO userData (username,password,email,signup_date) VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$date')";
    $result=mysql_query($query,$connection) or die (mysql_error()." Kann Tabelle der Datenbank nicht lesen!");
    }  

    function sendResponse ($status = 200, $body ='', $content_type = 'application/json'){
            $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . 'OK';
            header($status_header);
            header('Content-type:' . $content_type);
            echo $body;
        }
```

This is what happens in my iphone app:

```
 NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&error];      

         NSDictionary *jsonDictionaryResponse =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"json response = %@", jsonDictionaryResponse);
```

Comment: Can you not change the response and remove the HTML around it?

Comment: change what exactly ? I thought about changing the status code, but I am not sure whether this would be a good solution ... Is it OK to mess around with the status code ?

Comment: Just output the JSON. Why do you need the HTML - are you displaying it somewhere? If not, wrapping the JSON in HTML is pointless and counter-productive...

Comment: What Dave says - what is the point in this instead of outputting pure JSON straight away?

Comment: ok yes that is absolutely pointless... But still, I can't get it to work. I'll post the code into my question. I would appreciate it if somebody looked it through...

Comment: He doesn't add HTML code. Follow the `$body` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you don't add HTML-Tags around your JSON enocded string. So you could just parse the whole response body. I recommend you using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) (if your don't do already) or the [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

But please note, that you should chage your MIME-Type to `application/json` when sending JSON data and that it doesn't make sense to `json_encode` a string.

```
sendResponse(200, json_encode(array('SUCCESS Notification')), 'application/json');
```

Comment: I posted my code in the question. Could you please have a look if at least the php part is right ? Would really appreciate it ...

Comment: Okay, I'm not absolutely sure, what your app does, but your not responding with a real JSON Object. If you `json_encode` a string you will get a string. You'll have to encode an object or array.

Answer (score 0):

If its a properly formatted HTML (with start and end tags) then you can use any XML Parser like NSXMLParser or use [HPPLE](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) parser to parse HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure to what purpose you are sending an HTML-file with JSON in it but that is not a good practice.  HTML is a document and JSON is a data-structure wich you are now including as text in the body. Are you just using the JSON from the reponse and "throwing the rest away"? Cause then I agree with Pekka to change your output. I'm not sure how familiar you are with PHP but you can change the output of a page to anything you want.  Just don't put any html in the php-file you are requesting and set the ouput-type to json like this:

```
header('Content-type:text/json');
```

Otherwise you could also use regular expressions or the DOM-parser Pekka suggested.

Comment: Please add a whitespace between `Content-Type:` and `text/json.` (`Content-type: text/json`)